# How to use "May" to hope for something in a sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Is it right to use "may" as follows to wish for better days to come?

> May one day comes a time at which we get rid of all such burdens.

Answer (score 1):

Almost. The usage of **may** is acceptable, provided you insert "there" and use the bare infinitive of **close** for this hypothetical ("hope for", as you said) statement.

And you might want to consider *in which*, or simply *when*, rather than *at which* ( "at which" is not wrong, but it sounds a bit formal; "in which" refers to a period rather than an instant.)

That is, put it this way:

- May **there** one day **come** a time **when** we get  rid of such burdens.

Or this way:

- May **there** one day **come** a time **when** we *have gotten rid* of such burdens.
  (envisioning completed action)

Or this way:

- May **there** one day **come** a time **in which** we *are rid* of such burdens.
  (envisioning a better situation, without saying who will get rid of the burdens))

Comment: I agree with your answer - but it has left me wondering how we got this *may* usage. I've a feeling that God may have been involved at some stage. *May God bless all the children...*

Comment: Merriam-Webster puts it this way:  > used in auxiliary function to express a wish or desire especially in prayer, imprecation, or benediction **may the best man win**       See also https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nr2_DBRcQrY

Comment: One of my favourite songs - from 1965. I remember it well.